# Syntax error on website

Tags: web, google-analytics-firebase

I use to finish my first webpage, but i have a syntax error in the Code.

```
    Unexpected identifier 'GoogleAnalyticsObject'. Expected ')' to end a argument list.
```

And this is the code:

```
    ga('create', '(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){   (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),   m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)   })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');    ga('create', 'UA-73950445-1', 'auto');   ga('send', 'pageview');', 'auto');
```

Can someone help me to finde the error in the code?

Comment: There are nested single quotes (`'`).

Answer (score 0):

Why just not use the code from [Google doc](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/), like this

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-73950445-1', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```